# How to edit Contents in pdf in edge

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge, edit

[image: Screenshot of Pdf file]

Actually I got a pdf file today and it's contents are a mess, and the file is way too huge to go through page-by-page to find the required data, is there anyway I can edit the content like:

> Chapter - 1
>
> - Be sure to check this page!
> - remember this point!

or even like the following would work:

> - Chapter - 1
> - Chapter - 2

please help me out

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've got the solution for anyone having the same problem as mine, to edit, merge, or split pdfs anyone can consider using 'Wondershare PDFelement' it's a really cool app with tons of features that I found out while searching for solutions for my problem. The app has a really cool interface and you can add, edit or delete bookmarks and save the changes. The free version has limited features and also leaves a watermark but I am ok with it, however you can always buy the pro version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to edit the title of the contents highlighted in the picture below?

[image]

If yes, it is not possible to edit those contents for a PDF file using the Edge browser.

We can only use the options mentioned in the picture below to draw or highlight something on the PDF file. We can use an eraser to remove the drew or highlighted part. [**Note:** We cant use these options for the table of contents.]

[image]

Reference: [Table of contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-pdf#table-of-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Often the contents will have been written correctly like this as seen in current MS Edge.

If you have a faulty copy it could be one of three reasons either the Author/Publisher made a mistake OR it's riddled with trojan errors, OR the viewer hiccuped and may need updating.

[image]

Thus if still getting rubbish "Contents" entries, request the author or their publisher supply you a good copy that's fit for purpose. You paid good money for that copy.